# How to find a unit in the ring of integers which is different from $\pm1$ in $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

How to find a unit in the ring of integers which is different from $\pm1$ in $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$, where $\alpha$ is a root of $x^3+12x+8$.

Comment: What is a unit different unit? Do you mean a unit different from $1$ or $-1?$

Comment: @Justin yes, I have edited

Comment: How about $\alpha/2$?

Comment: Everything different from zero is a unit, as you have a field. Do you mean the ring of integers maybe?

Comment: @johnnycrab yes I mean in the ring of integers.

Comment: Since it's cubic equation it'll have roots 1, $w$ and $w^2$ try using this.

Comment: The usual way to proceed is first to determine the ring of integers $O_K$ of the field $K=\mathbf Q(\alpha)$. This is a bit boring, involving computation of discriminants. You can find a general approach in D. Marcus' "Number Fields", chapter 2, exercise 28 (with hints). Then an element $x \in O_K$ is a unit iff $N(x)=\pm 1$, where $N$ denotes the norm of $K/\mathbf Q$ .